# How to turn off matplotlib quiver scaling?

Tags: matplotlib

The `matplotlib.pyplot.quiver` function takes a set of "origin" points and a set of "destination" points and the plots a bunch of arrows starting at the "origin" points headed in the direction of the "destination" points.  However, there is a scaling factor so that the arrows don't necessarily end AT the "destination" points, they simply point in that direction.

e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

pts = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
end_pts = np.array([[2, 4], [6, 8]])

plt.quiver(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], end_pts[:,0], end_pts[:,1])
```

[image: the_picture]

Note that the vector in the bottom left starts at (1,2) (which I want), but does not end at (2,4).  This is governed by a `scale` parameter to the `quiver` function that makes the arrow longer or shorter.  How do I get the arrow to end at EXACTLY (2,4)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [quiver documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html) states

> To plot vectors in the x-y plane, with u and v having the same units as x and y, use `angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1`.

Note however that `u` and `v` are understood relative to the position. Hence you would need to take the difference first.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

pts = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
end_pts = np.array([[2, 4], [6, 8]])
diff = end_pts - pts

plt.quiver(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], diff[:,0], diff[:,1],
           angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1.)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks God! This should be the default behaviour! If one is plotting arrows on an axis then one would expect these arrows to actually pay attention to the axis…