# Quiver plot tail length

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this quiver plot, which shows directions. Is there a way I can increase the tail of the arrows and have less number of arrows making the plot a bit cleaner?

[image: Quiver plot Image]

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484900/how-to-turn-off-matplotlib-quiver-scaling?

Comment: You can simply slice your data to get fewer points.  `data[::2,::2]`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for matplotlib's [quiver plot is here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html):

- The parameters `X` and `Y` directly control the arrow locations
- The parameters `scale`, `scale_units`, `units`, `width`, `headwidth`, `headlength` and `headaxislength` control the size of the arrows.  There's a diagram at the bottom of the page linked above which shows which parts of the arrows are controlled by each parameter.  You will likely need to try several variants, depending on whether you want "thinner arrows", "shorter arrows", or "arrows with smaller heads", and to what degree you need to change them.

Depending on the degree to which you want to change the frequency of arrow locations, and whether or not you have explicit `X` and `Y` matrices, you can either resample (as @him) suggested in the comments on your Q (e.g. data = data[::2,::2] - also compare [this script on resampling](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/resample.html)) or you can construct `X` and `Y` explicitly from the input ranges:

```
import numpy as np
xvect = np.array(range(minx,maxx,stepx))
yvect = np.array(range(miny,maxy,stepy))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xvect, yvect)
```

The latter has the benefit of allowing you to provide more-fine control of the resolution, and you could even modify the construction of `xvect` and `yvect` (or replace `np.meshgrid()` with a custom function) to provide higher resolution in some places and lower resolution in others.

Note that whatever scheme you use to construct the plot, the position matrices `X` and `Y`, the direction matrices `U` and `V`, and the color matrix `C` all need the same dimensions. See the quiver plot docs above for the definition and default values for each of those matrices.